# What happens during TASM/zi and TLINK/v ? x86

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos, tasm

What exactly happens when I type tasm/zi .asm 
and then: tlink/v .obj 
what is the purpose of writing these lines. 
( I'm using DOSBOX )
Thanks!

Comment: `tasm` assembles an ASM file into an object file. The `/zi` option includes full debug information into the object file. `tlink` is a linker that takes object file(s), libraries etc and combines them together and emits an executable program (in this case an MS-DOS EXE program). The `/v` option with `tlink` tells the linker to output full symbolic debugging information. This is useful if you use a debugger like `td` (Turbo Debugger).

Comment: This question is likely hard to answer to the level of detail you are interested in because the Turbo assembler and linker are closed-source programs.  However, they used to be quite popular, so it's likely that some people know them to the detail you are interested in.